# Is there a built-in Three.js heightmap function?

Tags: javascript, three.js, heightmap

I am currently working on a game in JavaScript, in Three.js. I am curious if I can add a height map to the walls that I have to make them more realistic (see image). [An image of the game design with the wall that is 2D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4k2d.png).

All the tutorials that I have seen use planes instead of rectangles. I am currently using rectangles, and would rather not switch, but if there is no solution with rectangles, I would be happy to know.

I am currently using the class NewObstacle() to make my rectangles:

```js
const wallTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const wallTextureTexture = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: wallTexture.load('wall_textures/wall_3.jfif')
})

class NewObstacle{
  constructor(sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, xPos, yPos, zPos){
    this.sizeX = sizeX
    this.sizeY = sizeY
    this.sizeZ = sizeZ
    this.xPos = xPos
    this.yPos = yPos
    this.zPos = zPos
  }
  makeCube(){
    const cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(this.sizeX, this.sizeY, this.sizeZ)
    this.box = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, /*new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:
0x505050})*/wallTextureTexture)
    this.box.material.transparent = true
    this.box.material.opacity = 1
    this.box.position.x = this.xPos
    this.box.position.y = this.yPos
    this.box.position.z = this.zPos
    scene.add(this.box)
  }
}
```

What is the easiest way to implement height maps?

Comment: Here's an official example using [displacement map](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_displacementmap) You can move the `displacementScale` slider to see how it works. It basically uses [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/models/obj/ninja/displacement.jpg) to make the white parts displace a lot & the black parts displace a little. You can see the source code by clicking on the bottom-right `< >` icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `displacementMap` property on the material.

[This](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MayaLT/files/Surface-Relief--Displacement-maps-htm.html#:%7E:text=Displacement%20maps%20are%20grayscale%20textures,on%20an%20otherwise%20flat%20object.) article states:

> Displacement maps are grayscale textures you map to objects to create true surface relief (elevations and depressions) on an otherwise flat object.

First load you texture:

```js
const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const displacement = loader.load('yourfile.extension');
```

Next you create the material. I recommend using `MeshStandardMaterial`. This is how you would define your material:

```js
const material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000, //Red
    displacementMap: displacement,
    displacementScale: 1
});
```

We already know that `displacementMap` is going to use the grayscale image to create depressions and elevations on the plane, but the `displacementScale` is how *much* the plane is affected by the `displacementMap`.

That should do it!